# Trigger After Insert Update -cant update table

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

i have this Trigger in my MySql:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER `mydatabase`.`content_AFTER_INSERT` AFTER INSERT ON `content` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

  UPDATE member
           SET member.points = member.points +10, member.postcountT = member.postcountT +1

           WHERE  member.user_id = NEW.owner;
END
```

and this error comes if i insert data into the "content" table:

```
Can't update table 'member' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.
```

how can i resolve this? thanks.

Comment: Can you show the procedure where you are inserting the data into `Content`?

Comment: the alias `NEW` is for which table?

Comment: `INSERT INTO content (ispic, text, city, comments, points, create2, color, lat, lon, owner, tempid, isHome,owner_id) VALUES (2,?,?,0,0,NOW(),?,?,?,?,?,?,(SELECT member.id FROM member WHERE user_id=?))`